# Complex Data Structures in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am working on a project that needs a Java library that can give me implementations for different Trees and Graphs (directed and undirected).

AFIO Java does not contain any implementation of Trees and Graphs by degault.

I tried to **google** it. But the results I got were more of towards visualization stuff. (Though I got some related to networks too, but that is not what I was looking for)

Do you know of any Java libraries that can support my need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/) used for working with graphs, with excellent results.

Side note, a tree is "just" a specific type of graph.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) for graphs, [Google g-trees](http://code.google.com/p/g-trees/) for trees.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting, immutable datastructures in http://functionaljava.org/